# pdf of product of standard normal and uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Even though this question has been answered somewhat [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672521/product-of-standard-normal-and-uniform-random-variable), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428060/product-of-uniform-and-normal-distribution), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479058/variance-of-product-of-uniform-and-normal-random-variables), I'd like to ask what the probability density function of $z = x y$ is, where $x \sim \mathcal{U}[-1,1]$, $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $z$ are all univariate. Furthermore, what are the mean and variance of $z$? (By symmetry, it is easy to see $\mathbb{E}[z] = 0$, but I want a more rigorous proof.)

Edit: What if $x \sim \mathcal{U}[-\theta,\theta]$?

Comment: The variance is $\Bbb E[Z^2]=\Bbb E[X^2]\Bbb E[Y^2]=\int_{-1}^1\tfrac12x^2dx\cdot1=\tfrac13$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $|X|,\,|Y|$ have respective PDFs $1_{[0,\,1]}(x),\,\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}1_{[0,\,\infty)}(y)$, $|Z|=|X||Y|$ [has on-$[0,\,\infty)$ PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) $\int_0^1x^{-1}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}e^{-z^2/(2x^2)}dx=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma\left(0,\,\tfrac12z^2\right)$ in terms of the [upper incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition). Since $X,\,Y$ have symmetric distributions, $Z$'s PDF on $\Bbb R$ is $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}\Gamma\left(0,\,\tfrac12z^2\right)$.

Comment: By definition of the upper incomplete Gamma function, $\Gamma(s,t) = \int_t^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x} dx $, how do you see $\int_0^1x^{-1}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}e^{-z^2/(2x^2)}dx \stackrel{?}{=} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma\left(0,\,\tfrac12z^2\right)$

Comment: I double-check the integral quantity by [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+x%5E%28-1%29+*++exp%28-1%2F2+*+z%5E2%2Fx%5E2%29%2C+x%2C+0%2C+1), it's actually correct.

Comment: @kensaii Substitute $u:=z^2/(2x^2)$ so $dx/x=-du/(2u)$.